# How to use Selenium in Python Anaconda to press the load more button?

Tags: python, selenium

I am very new in python, I would like to know the correct xpath in selenium for clicking the load more button. I have attached the screen capture of my python code, and also the website html for your reference.

[image]

```html
<div class="show-more">
   <button class="btn" data-url="https://example.com">
      <svg class="icon">
         <use xlink:href="#chevron-circle-thin"></use>
      </svg>
   </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.get('your url')

time.sleep(5) # This allows the website to load

clickElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath('full xpath').click() #This is the full xpath so you just want copy the full xpath for the element.
```

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/K20cnuR.png  Sorry i dont have the full path, i just waNT to press the button to load more items so i can crawl. #Error message: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[@button class="btn"] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[@button class="btn"]' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.93)

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/K20pcrT.png   why it takes forever to load

Comment: can u send the website link

Comment: here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67555771/how-to-use-python-selenium-to-crawl-all-the-products

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='show-more']/button").click()
```

Just grab the class of the div and locate the button not too sure if btn for the button is unique and just use .click().